# I have been trying to create a csv file from data recieved from a web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

as of right now i have a working code which is a web scraper that logs into indeed job search site. My issue now is tha I need to create a csv file that shows every single job position that was found, it gives me the numer of positions available and the description of one of them. Hope i can get some help, I would greatly apreciate it.

```
import re
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

jk_pattern = re.compile(r"jk:\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'")

params = { "q": "mechanical+engineer", "l": "united+states", "start": 0 }
url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs"
job_keys = set()

for x in range(10):
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    if not response.status_code == 200:
        break
    else:
        keys = jk_pattern.findall(response.text)
        if len(keys) > 0:
            for key in keys:
                job_keys.add(key)
    
    params['start'] += 20
    sleep(randint(0, 3))

len(job_keys)

template = "https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk={}"

jk = job_keys.pop()
job_url = template.format(jk)
response = requests.get(job_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("div", id="jobDescriptionText").text)

def get_record(card):
    """Extract job data from a single record"""
    
    job_title = card.h2.a.get('title')
    company = card.find('span', 'company').text.strip()
    job_location = card.find('div', 'recJobLoc').get('data-rc-loc')
    post_date = card.find('span', 'date').text
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    summary = card.find('div', 'summary').text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
    job_url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + card.h2.a.get('href')

    # this does not exists for all jobs, so handle the exceptions
    salary_tag = card.find('span', 'salaryText')
    if salary_tag:
        salary = salary_tag.text.strip()
    else:
        salary = ''  
        
    record = (job_title, company, job_location, post_date, today, summary, salary, job_url)
    return record


def main(position, location):
    """Run the main program routine"""
    records = []
    url = get_url(position, location)
    
    # extract the job data
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        cards = soup.find_all('div', 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
        for card in cards:
            record = get_record(card)
            records.append(record)
        try:
            url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + soup.find('a', {'aria-label': 'Next'}).get('href')
        except AttributeError:
            break
        
    # save the job data
    with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['JobTitle', 'Company', 'Location', 'PostDate', 'ExtractDate', 'Summary', 'Salary', 'JobUrl'])
        writer.writerows(records)
```

Comment: How is `main()` called?

Comment: Try to test out how often for card in cards: runs. So you see if soup.find_all('div', 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard') works as intended.